# Method for determining the root cause behind a drop in business performance

Tags: business-intelligence

What methods are there for determining the **root cause behind a drop in business performance?** My question is best explained with a very simple example...

---

There are two Widget Factories (A and B).

Each factory has an output ($y_X$) given by the product of `number_of_workers` ($N_X$) and `avg_production_rate_per_worker` ($r_X$):

$$y_X = N_X \cdot r_X$$

where $X$ refers to the factory, and the total output is:

$$y = y_\mathrm{A} + y_\mathrm{B}$$

From week 1 to week 2, the total output decreases from 1,000 to 500.

**Is there a way of determining the root metrics/dimensions behind this drop?** i.e., has $y$ gone down due to $N_\mathrm{A}$, or $N_\mathrm{B}$, or $r_\mathrm{A}$, etc.?

I have data in the following form:

```
                 Number of  Avg. Production   Total
Week   Factory   Workers    Rate per Worker   Output
----------------------------------------------------
1      A         10         10/week           100 
2      A         15         10/week           150
...    ...       ...        ...               ...
1      B         10         10/week           100
2      B          5         15/week            75
```

Comment: For example, a drop in $y$ may be due to a:
 1) **local change** - a single metric in *one* factory decreasing, e.g.:
   a) a bout of flu meaning many staff are off sick (reduces `number_of_workers`),
   b) automated production line breaks meaning production has to be done manually (reduces `avg_production_rate`)
 2) **global change** - a single metric *over both* factories decreasing, e.g.:
   a) a national holiday meaning more staff off due to annual leave (reduces `number_of_workers`) or
   b) a new company-wide QA process meaning more checks are added (reduces `avg_production_rate`)

Comment: Any ideas? Can Sensitivity Analysis help? Can I change data to logs and use Structured Equation Modelling?

Comment: Graph models perhaps?